# Сложность с циклом

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит 10 чисел (каждое не больше 12).
Нужно вывести их среднее значение.
Как это сделать с помощью цикла и без массивов?
Моя попытка:

```
int main(){

setlocale(0, "");

int a, d=0, j=1, v;

do{
    cout<<"Введите 10 цифр"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    d=d+a;

        if(j==10){v=d/10;}

    }while(j==10);
    cout<<v;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Надо сложить все числа и поделить на 10

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваше решение.

Answer (score 3):

Суммируйте прямо в цикле.

```
double sum = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    double d;
    cin >> d;
    sum += d;
}

cout << d/10;
```

Примерно так...

Comment: cout != cin :-)

Comment: Ну да, конечно :)

Answer (score 2):

Легко и просто:

```
double r = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int v = 0;
    std::cin >> v;
    r += v;
}

r /= 10;
std::cout << r << "\n";
```